# Should the 'f' be sustained or replayed in Rachmaninoff op. 43, variation XVIII (piano)?

Tags: piano, notation, sustain

In Rachmaninoff's well known variation 18 of opus 43, Rhapsody on a Theme of Paganini, the first few measures of the piano part show an 'f' that's somehow repeated during the length of the first note:

[image: First five measures of the piano part of Rachmaninoff's opus 43, variation 18, with repeated 'f's highlighted]

How should this be played? Should the 'f' be replayed? Or should the 'f' remain sustained during the length of the first instance? Is this just to show the that conceptually it's all still triplets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The F should be replayed, but in a way that shows it's in a different voice than the initial F. Here, most likely the second F would be played a bit more quietly than the first, since the first is attached to the melody, while the second is clearly accompaniment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, replay the F and pretend you didn't. :) This is only half kidding. You need to keep both voices in mind at the same time: the F that is part of the chord and the F that is part of the accompaniment.